# Phpmyadmin - connection for controluser failed PHPMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed xampp and i am trying to connect to localhost/phpmyadmin. 
I get an error. Connection for controluser as defined in the configuration failed. 
I can't even log in as username: root, no password .
Here are my configuration:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily comment out the controluser and controlpass directives (by adding `//` to the beginning of the line). Then log in as normal; if you wish to use the advanced features you can reset the password for the 'pma' user and set the new password in `config.inc.php`.